# Can MacOS be run on a PC?

Tags: macos

In order to fully clarify my question, here's what I intend.

I have a notebook running Windows 10 on an Intel Core 2 Duo and 3 GB of RAM.

I intend to run MacOS (the apple operating system) on this notebook; either standalone or sideways (2 OS on the same machine).

*This question might appear super-silly but I happen to be a complete Apple noob.*

So, I don't even know if Apple sells its OS as a standalone product. And basically that's what I am trying to inquire.
I skimmed through various high-end/expert/in-complete posts online that mentioned that MacOS can be downloaded from the iTunes or something like that, but I have no idea what that means. Or if that is even legal or not.

I don't want a limited solution for this like running a virtual machine, as I intend to develop for iOS using this.

**I want to run the actual/complete (not necessarily the latest, but late) version of Apple OS, without having to buy a Mac.**

*Remember, I am a noob. So, please be as, specific and thoroughly detailed and clear; as possible.*

*If possible, please give a step by step solution.*

Thank you for the time.

Comment: It is possible to do, but is of dubious legality as it is specifically forbidden in the MacOS EULA to use it on non-Apple hardware.  MacOS on a PC is known as "Hackintosh".

Comment: @Mokubai First, the question is new in the sense that it attends to the noobs. Secondly, since this is a Q/A site and not a discussion board, can you at least point me towards a step-by-step guide of this "Hackintosh" process. Thanks.

Comment: You are apparently not familiar with the process of [googling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_%28verb%29). The process of finding information on the internet and analyzing search results is described [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gwebsearcheducation/lessonplans). After you read all this, you should understand that you can _google for "Hackintosh"_ and most likely will quickly stumble upon several sites with exactly the information you seek.

Comment: You apparently are not used to reading full sentences/paragraphs. I did mention that I am a total newbie to the Mac World and did search online but got confused, therefore posted here. This is a Q/A site. If you can't or don't want to answer then you don't have to. However, spending your time on explaining a non-inquired phenomenon (googling) and yet not on the actual question, is pointless. Although, I did google the initial replies and found a lead. If you really meant to help you could have recommended to google 'TonyMacx86' instead. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Zzz Hackintosh questions are considered off-topic here due to it being a legal grey area (see [meta](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed)). I don't know where to go for Hackintosh questions as I don't own a Mac nor do I have any reason to need to run MacOS. [apple.se] *might* allow questions, but they seem [undecided](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2/can-one-ask-hackintosh-questions-on-ask-different) though I doubt they will accept them either.

Answer (score 0):

Apple made sure that their OS can only be used on their computers. You can find guides on the net how to install on a PC but it's complicated because many technical workarounds are needed, and often it still won't work.

And no, it's not legal to do so.

Comment: Alright thanks for the reply. Can you mention one such how-to guide that is the most elaborate. I have got to try this. Thanks.